# Why the address bar changes but i dont go to the page i want?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

When i click on Mounth, only the address bar changes (into `localhost:3000/subscription/Mounth`) but i dont go to this page. Cant understand where is my mistake

**Root.jsx**

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom"
import Layout from "../Layout/Layout"
import Main from "../Main/main"
import Subscription from "../Subscription/subscription"
import Mounth from "../Subscription/Mounth"



function Root(){
    return(
        <>
    
          <Routes>
            <Route  element={<Layout/>}>
                <Route path="/" element={<Main/>}/>
                <Route path="subscription" element={<Subscription/>}>
                 <Route path="Mounth" element={<Mounth/>}/>
                </Route>
            </Route>
          </Routes>
          
        </>
    )
}

export default Root
```

**Subscription.jsx**

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom"
function Subscription(){
    return(
        <>
            <Outlet /> 
       
            <div className="main-content">
            <div className="container-primary">
                <div className="subscription-primary">
          
                    <form className="search-bar">
                        <input placeholder="Поиск" className="search-bar__input"/>
                    </form>
                    <h1 className="primary-title">Subscription</h1>
                    <h2 className="subscription-primary__title">Choose:</h2>
                    <ul className="subscription-primary__list">
                        <li className="subscription-primary__item">
                            <Link className="subscription-primary__link"  to="Mounth">
                                <div className="subscription-primary__bg">
                                    <span className="subscription-primary__mounth">1 month</span>
                                    <h3 className="subscription-primary__price">
                                        2499 &#8381;
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
             
                    <div className="promo">
                        <form className="promo__form" action="">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="" className="promo__field"/>
                            <button type="submit" className="promo__btn primary-btn">Accept</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

     
        </>
    )
}
```

When i want to go to Subscription page from Home page it works correctly, but doesnt from Subscription to Mounth, i use react-router-dom v6

Comment: Can you [edit] to clarify what exactly you are clicking on? See [mcve]. I think this means including your `Navbar` component at least.

Comment: Are you wanting to render `Mounth` on `"/mounth"` or `"/subscription/mounth"`? If you want it on `"/subscription/mounth"` then your routes are incorrect. If you want it on `"/mounth"` then the link is incorrect.

Comment: It is a card, when i click on it, i go to the Sub page where there are another 4 cards, but when i click on one of them, the address bar changes but i dont go to that card page.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. I guess it's simpler to ask, "Do you want `Subscription` and `Mounth` to render at the same time?" I guess it's moot now since you've already accepted an answer, so I suppose it worked for you. Cheers.

Comment: Mounth component is in the Sub page as one of the 4 cards, and when i click on it, i should be directed to this card page.

Comment: yes, it worked, but it  made another problem , because  when i click on one link twice, and then on another link, again the address bar changes but i dont go to this link page

Comment: "Pages" in React apps are really just an abstraction, i.e. just a bunch of conditional rendering in what is really just a Single Page App (SPA). Saying you want something to open in a page doesn't explain much. Do you want it on its own "page" by itself, or on the same "page" with the `Subscription` UI?

Comment: Again, the issue seems to be in what/where the links are rendered and how they are linking to other routes. If your question/issue is still unresolved then can you [edit] and add all the relevant code you are working with?

Comment: I added, the Sub page, there is a Link which i click on, and again, the Link stops working after a while or after a certain time, the address bar changes but i'm not redirecting to the pages

Comment: It's as I suspected with where the link was being rendered and where it was linking to. I don't see anything suspicious here that would cause a link to stop working altogether though. Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) that reproduces the issue you see that we could inspect live?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place `Mounth` route inside `Subscription` route in order to make `/subscription/mounth` url work:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
    <Route index element={<Main />} />
    <Route path="subscription" element={<Subscription />}>
      <Route path="mounth" element={<Mounth />} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Also don't forget to add `<Outlet />` inside `Subscription.jsx` so it will render the child route:

```
function Subscription() {
  // Some code...

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Some code */}
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: there is one problem, when i click on one link twice, and then on another link, again the address bar changes but i dont go to this link page.

Comment: It depends on how did you organize navigation. Extend with more information, please? Are you using <Link />, useNavigation hook or something else?

Comment: Hi, i use Link to navigate

Comment: Could you please provide code of the <Link /> component (update the description of the issue)? The usage should be something like `<Link to="/subscription/mounth">Go to Mounth</Link>`, but it's important to see the whole component to say exactly what's happening. Sometimes it's tricky, sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

Make mounth a child of subscription route, a nested route:

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom"
import Layout from "../Layout/Layout"
import Main from "../Main/main"
import Subscription from "../Subscription/subscription"
import Mounth from "../Subscription/Mounth"


function Root(){
    return(
        <>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Layout/>}>
                <Route path="/" element={<Main/>}/>
                <Route path="subscription" element={<Subscription/>}>
                    <Route path="mounth" element={<Mounth/>}/>
                </Route>
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </>
    )
}

export default Root
```

Comment: bro, thx for the answer, but it doesnt work without <Outlet /> inside Subscription.jsx